# Scheme sequencing

Tags: scheme, syntactic-sugar, sequencing

I am new to Scheme and I am trying to familiarize myself with the language by reading [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html). I am a bit confused about sequencing.

First, I understand that `begin` keyword is introduced to allow sequencing, needed so that manipulation over mutable structures is easier. What I don't understand is that sometimes they use sequencing as follows (motivated by example on page 268 of SCIP):

```
(define (stuff-0)
   (+ 1 2)
   (+ 1 3)
   'ok)
```

while the same can be implemented using `begin`:

```
(define (stuff-1)
  (begin
    (+ 1 2)
    (+ 1 3)
    'ok))
```

Is there a semantic difference between those two or the first one is just a syntactic sugar for the second?

Second, aside from practical importance, do we theoretically need the `begin` construct? I imagine for each sequence we need we could write a cascade of procedures that implement the sequence. It is impractical of course, but I am just interested in expressiveness of the language without the `begin` construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple: inside a procedure, there's always an *implicit* `begin`. So this:

```
(define (f x)
  (begin
    <expression 1>
    <expression 2>
    <returned value>))
```

... Is completely equivalent to this:

```
(define (f x)
  <expression 1>
  <expression 2>
  <returned value>)
```

And no, there isn't any semantic difference, the second form above is just syntactic sugar for the first form. And the `begin` form is necessary, because there has to be a way to perform a sequence of expressions *just for their effect* in the specified order. Remember: in a `begin` (or for that matter, inside a procedure - it's the same) all the expressions get executed in the order they appear, their resulting values being essentially ignored, and only the last expression's value is returned at the end.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the part where you speak about `begin` being necessary? Can you give me an example where using `begin` is absolutely the only way to go. My impression is since Scheme evaluates arguments of a procedure before the body, we can simulate sequencing by cascading procedures.

Comment: For example: how would you cascade procedures for this? `(define x 10) (define (f) (set! x (add1 x)) x) (f)` notice that the `begin` is implicit inside the `f` procedure, and that the first line in the procedure produces an effect, not a value

Comment: First, you'd have to define `cascade` to receive a variable number of parameters, as `begin` can have an arbitrary number of expressions. Second, it won't work because the evaluation order of the arguments to a procedure is undefined - and `begin` guarantees the order of evaluation of its expressions

Comment: To your first remark: I am aware of this and this is why `begin` is very useful. Without it, you would always need to write a specific cascade for a specific problem, but I am currently putting that aside. To your second remark, it seems that Racket evaluates arguments left from right [link](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/application.html).

Comment: Second remark: you can't count on it. It's implementation dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Every define special from contains an implicit begin clause.

To the neophyte the second example is clearer, but to the experienced it is just noise.

One place you'll need a begin construct often is as the then or else clause of an if statement.  You also need it in within anonymous functions.

Answer (score 1):

An explicit `begin` is not needed.  If you need to sequence something, but don't have `begin`, then you do this:

```
((lambda () <body1> <body2> ...))
```

The above is, in fact, exactly how you would implement `begin` as a macro.  Here is the syntactic definition from R7RS:

```
 (define-syntax begin
    (syntax-rules ()
      ((begin exp ...)
       ((lambda () exp ...)))))
```

So your statement "I understand that `begin` keyword is introduced to allow sequencing" isn't really correct.  `begin` is introduced as syntactic sugar on the fundamental sequencing construct of `lambda`.

Comment: But that works only because a `begin` is added implicitly as part of the procedure's body, so you need a `begin` for this to work.

Comment: A lambda's body produces a sequence; because it does a `lambda` can be used to define `begin`.  The `lambda` is more fundamental.

Comment: As far as my knowledge in lambda calculus goes, there is no sequencing in lambda expressions. In Scheme, there is sequencing. I was curious is it possible to simulate sequencing by just applying functions, taking into consideration Scheme's strict call-by-value evaluation strategy.

Comment: If `lambda` only allows one body form (and `begin` does not exist), then you achieve sequencing using repeated function application.  For example sequence `(display 'foo) (display 'bar)` becomes `((lambda x (display 'bar)) (display 'foo))`